# how to resize featured image is auto croped small and low-quality

Tags: wordpress

When I upload a featured image in Wordpress, it decreases the size of image. The quality of images is also much lower than original images. How can I get Wordpress to have larger, higher-quality featured images?

btw there is no function `the_post_thumbnail` in function.php file

I try below code it didn't help me

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail( array(300,207) ); ?>
```

**Found the answer at [www.studiograsshopper.ch](http://www.studiograsshopper.ch) :)**

Finally i found the solution by adding this code to theme function.php

```
set_post_thumbnail_size( 300, 207, true ); //(cropped)
update_option('thumbnail_size_w', 300);
update_option('thumbnail_size_h', 207);
update_option('thumbnail_crop', 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Look for WordPress guides or tutorials and see your problem.

Comment: i google it but i ddnt found a solution. here is the site. [link](http://www.mtelizadental.com.au)